# Using jquery AJAX Post method in Google app script

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using Google script for Google sheets and i want to run jQuery code in google script or use some method in google apps script to do like this:

```
var url = 'https://example.com/message?token=83763g87x';

var data = {
    money: '333', 
    body: 'Hello, Andrew!', // Message
};

// Send a request
$.ajax(url, {
    data : JSON.stringify(data),
    contentType : 'application/json',
    type : 'POST'
});
```

Comment: You need [tag:urlfetch]

Answer (score 1):

There it is :

```
var url = 'https://example.com/message?token=83763g87x';

var data = {
    money: '333', 
    body: 'Hello, Andrew!', // Message
};

// Send a request
var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  // Convert the JavaScript object to a JSON string.
  'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
};
UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
```